# How to create an array with <input>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I want to create an array with a html  element. My main problem is, that i just get a string inside an array but no array.

Example: input is: 1,5,7,3,4
inside an array it look like this: `["1,5,7,3,4"]` but i want it like this: `[1,5,7,3,4]`

I look for a solution made in javascript or better in jquery!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) will convert a string to an array.

```
var myArray = document.getElementById('myInput').value.split(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function to convert the string to an array.

For example:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput">1,5,7,3,4</input>

var myInput = $('#myInput').val();
var arr = myInput.split(','); // [1,5,7,3,4]
```

Comment: I know that, thanks. Quentin wrote the vanilla-style, I thought the jQuery equivalent might be useful.

Comment: Ah yes, multiple options is never a bad idea :)